# I requested my Code Golf account be deleted, but got an email saying my Stack Overflow account will be deleted!

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

I asked that my Code Golf account be deleted since the option doesn't show up on my User Preferences page.  Then I got an email saying they received my request to delete my Stack Overflow account!!

> Hello,
>
> You recently sent a request to have your Stack Overflow profile
>   removed. We're sorry to see you go! This email is just to let you know
>   your request has been received, and we will respond with help ASAP.
>
> Thanks, The Stack Exchange Team

I want to keep all my Stack Exchange (and Overflow) accounts, just not Code Golf!  What do I do?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You requested deletion from Stack Overflow, so the system assumed you were trying to delete your Stack Overflow account because it can't parse the text you typed into the free-form box. If you would like your Code Golf account deleted, you need to visit the Code Golf site and [request deletion there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: Ohh snap.  I think when I clicked someone's guide to deleting accounts I didn't realize it was specifically to SO (I thought it was SE-ecosystem universal and I specified in the box).

Do you think my SO account will still be deleted?  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Eventually you'll receive instructions. Just ignore them and nothing will happen.